# Custom shapes in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In my project the shapes I created were spheres and I used an image as texture for material...

How can I make a custom shape (not sphere, rectangle, etc.)? For example, how can I create a halfsphere?

My code for now:

```
// create a texture
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('red.png');

// create a sphere shape
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 16, 16);

// give it a shape red color
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});

// create an object
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are multiple ways to use geometry in Three.js, from [importing models](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models) that were exported via a 3D editor (e.g. Blender), to creating geometry from scratch.

One way would by to create instance of *THREE.Geometry* and add vertices, and then work out how those connect to add face indices, but this not an easy way to do it.

I would suggest starting with the existing geometries (found in the extras/geometries package) like THREE.CubeGeometry, THREE.CylinderGeometry, THREE.IcosahedronGeometry, THREE.OctahedronGeometry, etc.)

Additionally there are some really nice classes that allow you to generate extrusions (THREE.ExtrudeGeometry) and lathes(THREE.LatheGeometry). For extrusions, see [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes).

You mentioned creating half a sphere. That's an ideal candidate for using LatheGeometry.

All you need to do is create a half-circle path (as an array of Vector3 instances) and pass that to the lathe so it revolves the half-circle into 3D - a halfsphere.

Here's an example:

```
var pts = [];//points array - the path profile points will be stored here
var detail = .1;//half-circle detail - how many angle increments will be used to generate points
var radius = 200;//radius for half_sphere
for(var angle = 0.0; angle < Math.PI ; angle+= detail)//loop from 0.0 radians to PI (0 - 180 degrees)
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.cos(angle) * radius,0,Math.sin(angle) * radius));//angle/radius to x,z
geometry = new THREE.LatheGeometry( pts, 12 );//create the lathe with 12 radial repetitions of the profile
```

Plug that geometry into your mesh and Bob’s your uncle!

Optionally, you can centre the mesh/pivot using GeometryUtils:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
```

Comment: Thanks mate...I can see you know what you talking about...so do you have an idea how can I make the objects draggable? I saw some examples and found it got to do with Three.Ray...You know something about it?

Comment: Glad it helps. Whenever I want to do something with three.js I check if there's an example already :) [webgl_interactive_draggablecubes](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) is the place to start. You need to use the mouseup/mousedown/mousemove listeners. The idea is the mouse 2D coordinates are converted to 3D based on the camera and a ray is 'shot' through space in depth. Then there's a test to check if there's any objects on that ray/line(any intersections), if so, SELECTED is set to the 1st object in the list (if any)..etc

Comment: long story short, if you copy those 3 listeners into your project and have the SELECTED and INTERSECTED and projector variables at the top, it should work in your file as well.

Comment: I am always trying to find some three.js solutions...but there are not many. now I'm looking at this on : http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html...I want to do something similar,but not to randomally rotate  the cubes...I want to know what object was clicked and to drag it

Comment: Use the [draggable cubes](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) one: it's exactly what you need. If it's a problem that it's WebGL, simply change the renderer: `renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();//new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );` Won't look as pretty, but it works. Goodluck!