# How can I bind two shapes together as one in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Can I bind two different shapes together as one shape?

For example, binding sphere and cylinder together as one?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Kind of, yes. There are multiple options:

1. via hierarchy you can simply add one mesh to another using the `add()` function
2. via the GeometryUtil's `merge()` function to merge vertices and meshes of two *Geometry* objects into one
3. using a basic 3D editor that supports Boolean operations between meshes and exporting.

Method 1 is pretty straightforward:

```
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 16, 12), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2D303D, wireframe: true, shading: THREE.FlatShading }));

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 200, 16, 4, false), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2D303D, wireframe: true, shading: THREE.FlatShading } ));
cylinder.position.y = -100;
scene.add(sphere);
scene.add(cylinder);
```

Notice that 16 is repeated, so the subdivisions level in one mesh matches the other (for a decent look).

Method 2.1 - via GeometryUtils

```
// Make a sphere

var sg = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 16, 12);
// Make a cylinder - ideally the segmentation would be similar to predictable results
var cg = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 200, 16, 4, false);
// Move vertices down for cylinder, so it maches half the sphere - offset pivot
for(var i = 0 ; i < cg.vertices.length; i++)
    cg.vertices[i].position.y -= 100;

// Merge meshes
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(sg, cg);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sg, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2D303D, wireframe: true, shading: THREE.FlatShading }));
scene.add(mesh);
```

Method 2.2 merging a [Lathe half-sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284233/three-js-custom-shapes/8284842#8284842) and a cylinder:

```
var pts = []; // Points array

var detail = .1; // Half-circle detail - how many angle increments will be used to generate points
var radius = 100; // Radius for half_sphere
var total = Math.PI * .51;
for(var angle = 0.0; angle < total ; angle+= detail) // Loop from 0.0 radians to PI (0 - 180 degrees)
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,Math.cos(angle) * radius,Math.sin(angle) * radius)); // Angle/radius to x,z

var lathe = new THREE.LatheGeometry(pts, 16); // Create the lathe with 12 radial repetitions of the profile

// Rotate vertices in lathe geometry by 90 degrees
var rx90 = new THREE.Matrix4();
rx90.setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Vector3(-Math.PI * .5, 0, 0));
lathe.applyMatrix(rx90);

// Make cylinder - ideally the segmentation would be similar for predictable results
var cg = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 200, 16, 4, false);

// Move vertices down for cylinder, so it maches half the sphere
for(var i = 0 ; i < cg.vertices.length; i++)
    cg.vertices[i].position.y -= 100;

// Merge meshes
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(lathe, cg);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(lathe, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2D303D, wireframe: true, shading: THREE.FlatShading}));
mesh.position.y = 150;
scene.add(mesh);
```

The one problem I can't address at the moment comes from the faces that are inside the mesh. Ideally, those would have normals flipped, so they wouldn't render, but I haven't found a quick solution for that.

The third is fairly straightforward. Most 3D packages allow Boolean operation on meshes (e.g., merging two meshes together with the ADD operation (meshA + meshB)). Try creating a cylinder and a sphere in [Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) (free and opensource), which already has a [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/143) exporter. Alternatively you can export an .obj file of the merged meshes from your 3D editor or choice and use the [convert_obj_three](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/convert_obj_three.py#L1) script.

I've found yet another method, which might be easier/more intuitive. Remember the Boolean operations I've mentioned above?

It turns out there is an awesome JavaScript library just for that: [Constructive Solid Geometry](https://github.com/evanw/csg.js):

[image: CSG library preview from the owner's GitHub page]

Chandler Prall wrote some handy functions to connect [CSG with three.js](http://chandler.prallfamily.com/2011/12/constructive-solid-geometry-with-three-js/). So with the CSG library and the [Three.js wrapper for it](http://chandler.prallfamily.com/labs/three/csg/ThreeCSG.js), you can simply do this:

```
var cylinder = THREE.CSG.toCSG(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 200, 16, 4, false), new THREE.Vector3(0, -100, 0));
var sphere   = THREE.CSG.toCSG(new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 16, 12));
var geometry = cylinder.union(sphere);
var mesh     = new THREE.Mesh(THREE.CSG.fromCSG(geometry), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
```

Which gives you a nice result (no problems with extra faces/flipping normals, etc.):

[image: Cylinder-sphere union with CSG and Three.js]

Comment: I'm trying all of those thing,thank for the answers! I asked this question since I'm trying to create 3D flower with number of shapes and textures. My purpose to bind the shapes,so I can rotate and drag the whole flower shapes and not every shape together as one shape

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Hello Enjoy's HelloFlower app](http://helloenjoy.com/helloflower/). In this case I would say, have an empty 'container' Object3D at the top, and then `add()` the petals, pistil, etc. to that so you can manipulate the group together. Something like the 1st suggestion, but instead of adding straight to the scene, adding to a container( `scene.add(container);container.add(flowerPartA);container.add(flowerPartB);//etc.` )

Comment: Wow! it's great example man...not exactly what I'm trying to build but there are some similar things.For the last couple of days I had a good progress. I hope that my final example that I will post,will help to beginner in Three.js to solve some small and bigger issues. But still there's some small things I'm still not familiar with...How can I create something like cylinder shape that starts in point X and ends in a point Y...for now the only thing I can figure out is just make a cylinder and rotate it?

Comment: @BorisD Yes,rotating is the right approach !You need to work out the rotation, but that's easy since **Object3D** has a `lookAt()` function and so does **Matrix4** which does most of the math for you. There is a catch though: the default pivot for a cylinder is at the centre of the mesh, so you might need to also do some offsetting because of that. I spotted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375288/three-js-cylinder-from-point-to-point) a few days back. Try to use the above mentioned. If you run into issues,try to reformulate your question and based on your trials then post again. HTH

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately, it does not work with Three.js r50 :( Do you know if the three.js wrapper around CSG has been updated ?

Comment: I updated a wrapper for Three.js r62. You can find it at *[csg-wrapper](https://github.com/kraag22/csg-wrapper)*.