# Can we cut a single 3D object along x-axis in three.js and WebGL?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

Can we crop part of a 3D obj. Object's hidden part should stay hidden moving camera and rotating with mouse. And other objects should stay completely visible always.

The code below crops everything going in x-axis, but I want to show one obj half and other full.

```
var localPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( -1, 0, 0 ), 1 );
renderer.clippingPlanes = [ localPlane ];
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/muaoqhmq/2/

*Want to keep the upper body always while rotating*

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html

Comment: It clips everything in a plane

Comment: Seems like you might be looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322759/three-js-bind-two-shapes-together-as-one/8328984#8328984

Comment: I want to load obj file and crop it to show half, when rotated hidden part should remain hidden

Comment: Clipping in three.js is done in world space. A work-around is to rotate the camera instead of the object. Or create a custom material.

Comment: If we choose to rotate camera, then can we show another object at clipped world space? I am afraid that is also not possible

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately till today this is almost impossible to cut or crop a 3D .obj object in Three.JS however 3D objecs can be cropped in any defined shap easily in other WebGl libraries like [BabylonJS](https://www.babylonjs.com/).

```
 mCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(mymesh);//convert mesh to CSG
 var box1 = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box1", 3, scene);//define cropping mesh
 box1CSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(box1);//convert cropping mesh to CSG
 var subCSG = mCSG.subtract(box1CSG);//cropped CSG
 newmesh = subCSG.toMesh("csg", mat0, scene);//convert cropped CSG to mesh
```

Comment: If you're looking for CSG in three.js, check [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322759/three-js-bind-two-shapes-together-as-one/8328984#8328984)

Comment: Just a quick note that is only works in Babylon for super simple meshes. Note sure if that's the same for three.js but I think they are based off the same library. Anything more complex than a couple boxes will exceed the maximum call stack size in the browser because it's recursive.