# Is it possible to cut parts of the shape 'Geometry' away in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to remove or cut away sections of shapes in Three.js?

For example, if I made a CylinderGeometry and wanted to "shave" the front of it away, so that the front was flat and the back was curved, like a half cylinder. Is this possible?

I need to be able to do it to the front and back of a cylinder, so just the sides are curved.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is possible. You can deal with triangles yourself, or use Boolean operations with a library like [constructive solid geometry](https://github.com/evanw/csg.js) to do mesh subtraction.

[image: CSG three.js]

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322759/three-js-bind-two-shapes-together-as-one/8328984#8328984) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284233/three-js-custom-shapes/8284842#8284842) for some suggestions related to manipulating geometry.

There are other [algorithms to slice a mesh](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/cutting-up-a-mesh-into-tiny-little-pieces/) that could be ported over, but it depends on how simple or complex you need this thing to be.

Comment: @George can you give an example, how to get stared if I want to deal with the triangles directly?

Comment: A mesh in three.js has [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) which allows you direct access to `vertices` (the 3d points) and `faces` (the triangles connecting these 3d points). At this stage you can move vertices around, you can add/remove faces and therefore modify your mesh any way you like. [GeometryUtils](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/GeometryUtils) may come in handy. How would you like to manipulate a mesh's geometry ?

Comment: Constructive Solid Geometry requires geometries of CSG, but I have them created with three.js. I was referring this http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/. I have to create doors and windows in the wall, but the methods used in it are all deprecated. Please suggest how it can be done.